# .Net Core 2.1 problem with JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

Tags: c#, token

Description of problem in screenshot below.

I sitting on this many hours and i still have no idea what i am doing wrong. 
I searched in google but i didn't find any solution. Maybe some of you have the same problem and know how to sort out. 
Thanks in advance

[image: sreenshot of my code]

Comment: I forgot to tell that i am using .net core 2.1

Comment: I think you are using the `new` keyword in wrong place. New is used to create an instance of the class. Since you have created once the instance there is no need for the `new` keyword.

Comment: thanks man it works :) propably it is a change in .netcore 2.1 btw in .netcore 2.0 it working but i really thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help you.